# fputcsv returns double values

Tags: php, fputcsv

So currently i'm trying to make a database exporting script, what I got is this:

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect("SERVER","USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE");
   $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `TABLE`;");
   unlink('testfile.csv');
   $fp = fopen("testfile.csv","w");
   fputcsv($fp,array("Col1","Col2","Col3"),";");
   while ($list = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     fputcsv($fp,$list,";");
  }
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

this seems to return `"Col1 Col1 Col2 Col2 Col3 Col3"`

While `fputcsv($fp,array($list[0],$list[1],$list[2]),";");` seems to work fine.
Is there a way to avoid this solution and do it by the Original $list array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$list = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

This should return the array as a numeric array rather than a mixed map which it defaults to. Try print_r on the output too to make sure it's what you expect.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php